# Unable to identify what to 'click' for next page using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to get search results from yahoo search using python - selenium and bs4. I have been able to get the links successfuly but I am not able to click the button at the bottom to go to the next page. I tried one way, but it could't identify after the second page.

Here is the link:

`https://in.search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=AwrwSY6ratRgKEcA0Bm6HAx.;_ylc=X1MDMjExNDcyMzAwMgRfcgMyBGZyAwRmcjIDc2ItdG9wLXNlYXJjaARncHJpZANidkhMeWFsMlJuLnZFX1ZVRk15LlBBBG5fcnNsdAMwBG5fc3VnZwMxMARvcmlnaW4DaW4uc2VhcmNoLnlhaG9vLmNvbQRwb3MDMARwcXN0cgMEcHFzdHJsAzAEcXN0cmwDMTQEcXVlcnkDc3RhY2slMjBvdmVyZmxvdwR0X3N0bXADMTYyNDUzMzY3OA--?p=stack+overflow&fr=sfp&iscqry=&fr2=sb-top-search`

This is what im doing to get data from page but need to put in a loop which changes pages:

```
page = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
lnks = page.find('div', {'id': 'web'}).find_all('a', href = True)

for i in lnks:
    print(i['href'])
```

Comment: Please add the code you are trying.

Comment: i just deleted that bit of code:/

Comment: So in simple term you want to navigate to next page, is my understanding correct? if so then you can use this selector `a[class='next']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to scroll down to the bottom. The next button is accessible without scrolling. Suppose you want to navigate 10 pages. The python script can be like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('Yahoo Search URL')
# Let's create a loop containing the XPath for next button
# As well as waiting for the next button to be clickable.
for i in range(10):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, '//a[@class="next"]'))
    navigate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="next"]').click()
```

Comment: got it! thanks so much. it hangs after 100th pg

Answer (score 1):

The next page button is on the bottom of the page so you first need to scroll to that element and then click it. Like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
next_page_btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.next")
actions.move_to_element(next_page_btn).build().perform()
time.sleep(0.5)
next_page_btn.click()
```

Comment: Thank you!! scrolling isnt needed though

Comment: Maybe in this particular case it works without scrolling. It depends on the technology the page built with. While if you do perform scrolling it will work in all the cases